# Quickfix (C++) Incorrect data format for value:40

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

I'm currently using one Quickfix application to talk to another Quickfix application using FIX 4.2.  Both applications are written by me in C++.  I'm currently having an issue when I send an  Order Cancel Request (FIX message type F).  The receiving Quickfix application keeps rejecting my FIX message with "Incorrect data format for value:40".

The problem is, I'm not even sending Tag 40 in my Order Cancel Request message!  I also checked my Data Dictionary and Tag 40 is not defined form Order Cancel Request messages.

Here is the Order Cancel Request message that I'm sending:

**11032020-16:50:43.837819:(INFO) (outgoing): (FIX.4.2:TT->OMS) [8=FIX.4.2|9=118|35=F|34=68|49=TT|52=20201103-21:50:43.837|56=OMS|11=453000000025|41=453000000024|54=1|55=IBM|60=20201103-21:50:43.836|10=244|]**

Here is what is being received by the server side and it's error message.

**20201103-21:50:43.839340000 : Message 68 Rejected: Incorrect data format for value:40**

---

Here is the FIX Reject message automatically generated by Quickfix:

**11032020-16:50:43.839388:(INFO) (outgoing): (FIX.4.2:OMS->TT) [8=FIX.4.2|9=109|35=3|34=63|49=OMS|52=20201103-21:50:43.839|56=TT|45=68|58=Incorrect data format for value|371=40|372=F|373=6|10=176|]**

As you can see, what I'm sending is exactly what's being received and there is no tag 40.  Does anybody have any idea's what might be happening here??

Comment: Two things: 1. are you using the correct dictionary, i.e. a FIX4.2 dictionary? The first line in the dictionary XML should tell you. 2. Are you sure that the rejection is not created by your code? I could imagine that you try to access the field 40 without checking for its presence first?!

Comment: Don't rely on your application's print statements-- sometimes they are misleading.  Use a FileLogFactory and look at the *messages.log file.